# Javascript, amend elements after clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to post a cloned section of a form but it doesnt submit all due to element names being identical.

Does anyone know the best process for changing input name attributes during a clone ?

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
     if (checkMACAddress()==true) {
     $("#test").clone().insertAfter("div.test-row:last");
     }
  });
});
    function checkMACAddress() {
               var valid = true;
                for ( var i = 0, l = document.getElementsByName("mac").length; i < l; i++ ) {
        var macAddress=document.getElementsByName("mac")[i].value;
        var macAddressRegExp=/^(?:[0-9A-F]{2}[:]?){5}(?:[0-9A-F]{2}?)$/i;

        if (macAddressRegExp.test(macAddress)==false) { //if match failed
            alert("MAC Invalid - Must be IEEE.802 example 00:3F:00:10:00:2C");
            valid=false;
        }
               }
        return valid;
    }
</script>
<h3>Account Details</h3>
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-4">
               <label>Destination Account Number*</label>
        [[input||type=text||name=Account||name_literal=Account||placeholder=12345||required=required]]
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<h3>Device Details</h3>
<h5>
        <button type='button'>Add Device</button>
</h5>
<div id="test" class="test-row">
    <div class="columns small-3">
        <label>MAC - IEEE.802 Format Only</label>  
        [[input||type=text||name=mac||name_literal=mac||placeholder=54781A139264||required=required]]
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-3">
        <label>Extension/Seat Number</label>
        [[input||type=text||name=seat||name_literal=seat||placeholder=200]]
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-3">
        <label>Display Name</label>
        [[input||type=text||name=station||name_literal=station||placeholder=reception desk]]
    </div>
```

Comment: which is the cloned element?

Comment: its the entire div "test"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way could be to work with an array syntax as field name, for example: `data[identifier][]`. Otherwise you'll need to modify the name attribute after cloning:

```
var c  = 0;
// each time you click on the button...
$(".clone").on('click',function(){
    // generate a new clone of complete test div..
    var klon = $( '#test').clone();
    // append it to parent element (or after existing, as you like)
    $('#test').parent().append(klon);
    // increase global counter...
    c++;
    // inside clone find all inputs 
    // (if you other form elements, you must add them in selector)
    klon.find('input').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            name = $this.attr('name');
        // update name attribute
        $this.attr('name', name + '_' + (c));

    });
});
```

See a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7e41kje8/3/) here. 
I still prefer the name / array solution, it is easier to handle server-side, because you can loop over the fields instead of asking for unkown amount of new fields.

Comment: This appends the cloned div name. How can you easily append the child elements within the div. child input name etc..

Comment: @RossBeer I have updated the answer and added a fiddle to demonstrate the dynamic change of the name attribute. As I comment in the answer, I would prefer the name/ array variant in your case for example mac[], seats[].